# Find and interate all SMS/MMS messages in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-mms

First and foremost, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6446831/2415237) particularly helpful.  However, it made me wonder how one goes about finding such information.

I can't seem to figure out how to iterate all the messages in my inbox.  My current solution uses `Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations")` in which I give use "_id" and "ct_t".  However, it seems I only find the three conversations in my phone despite having 30 msges (20 of them in the save conversation thread and the others divided between two other conversations).  Would make sense for such a statement `content://mms-sms/conversations`.  However, the other providers seem to deal only with SMS OR MMS.  Isn't there a way to just iterate the entire list of messages in this fashion where I replace `"content://mms-sms/conversations"` with something else?

```
public boolean refresh() {
    final String[] proj = new String[]{"_id","ct_t"};
    cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations"),proj,null,null,null);
    if(!(cursor.moveToFirst())) {
        empty = true;
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I iterate the messages with a next function

```
    public boolean next() {

        if(empty) {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        msgCnt = msgCnt + 1;

        Msg msg;
        String msgData = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ct_t"));
        if("application/cnd.wap.multipart.related".equals(msgData)) {
            msg = ParseMMS(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        } else {
            msg = ParseSMS(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        }


        if(!(cursor.moveToNext())) {
            empty = true;
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Isn't there a way to just iterate the entire list of messages in this fashion where I replace `"content://mms-sms/conversations"` with something else?

It is possible to get all MMS and SMS messages in a single query using the `content://mms-sms/complete-conversations` URL. For some odd reason, there is no `Uri` field for this in the [`Telephony.MmsSms` class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/master/src/java/android/provider/Telephony.java), but it's been available since at least Froyo.

Using this single query will certainly be more efficient than querying the tables separately, and any sorting, grouping, or filtering that needs to be done will definitely be faster performed by the SQLite engine than by manipulating Java collections.

Please note that you must use a specific `projection` for this query. You cannot pass `null` or the `*` wildcard. Furthermore, it would be advisable to include `MmsSms.TYPE_DISCRIMINATOR_COLUMN` (`"transport_type"`) in your `projection` - which will have a value of either `"mms"` or `"sms"` - to easily distinguish the message type.

The `selection`, `selectionArgs`, and `orderBy` arguments work as usual, and `null` can be passed for any or all of them.

Comment: With this being undocumented, and not being able to pass null or * for the projection, does anyone have a list of columns that could be returned?

Comment: @Bink It can be any combination of the column fields in `android.provider.Telephony.Mms` and `android.provider.Telephony.Sms`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Mike.  FWIW, I tried this URI and it only returned SMS, not MMS.

Comment: Did you try with only MMS columns, just to test? Are you sure the messages you're expecting to be MMS are actually MMS, and not something else, like RCS? What happens if you query the MMS Provider? That is, what's returned if you query `Telephony.Mms.CONTENT_URI`? I ran a quick test after you commented here, to make sure I remembered how this worked, and every came up as I was expecting. I would mention, though, that not every device/manufacturer adheres to the standards for those Providers. I've seen some really wierd DB structures and URI mappings from users here asking similar questions.

Comment: Sorry Mike—I jumped the gun on my comment.  MMS is there.  I was sorting by date and, it appears, MMS uses seconds and SMS is using milliseconds.  Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 12):

Well, what I am asking doesn't really seem possible.
For those just starting out on such tasks, it's advisable to learn about how [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) work in general.  Each Uri value added to the query returns access to specific tables.

Spending some time looking at the different [Telephony.Mmssms](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.MmsSms.html) tables that one can access and it seems, from my testing, that the only table you can access is using `"content://mms-sms/conversations` as using `"content://mms-sms"` leads to a null cursor.

Such is life, and it doesn't really make sense to iterate the messages that way since the content and method of extracting the data differ greatly based on whether or not the msg is an SMS or MMS message.  It makes sense to iterate and parse SMS and MMS messages separately and store the interesting data into the same class object type for one to manipulate how they would like at a later date.

Useful to such a topic would be the [Telephony.Sms documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.html).  Which is where one can find a [descriptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html) of the column index fields.  You can find the same information for [Telephony.Mms](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Mms.html) as well as the sub table [Telephony.Mms.Part](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Mms.Part.html#SEQ), with links to each of the base columns to describe the information.

With this being said, here is a solution to the question `How can I iterate all the SMS/MMS messages in the phone?` and here is the solution that worked for me.

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Not shown, Overrides,  button to call IterateAll();
    //implementations to follow
    IterateAll();
    public void ScanMMS();
    public void ScanSMS();
    public void ParseMMS(Msg msg);
    public Bitmap getMmsImg(String id);
    public String getMmsAddr(String id);
}
```

IterateAll() just calls the two different functions

```
IterateAll() {
    ScanMMS();
    ScanSMS();
}
```

ScanMMS() will iterate through the `content://mms` table extracting the data from each MMS.

```
public void ScanMMS() {
        System.out.println("==============================ScanMMS()==============================");
        //Initialize Box
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms");
        String[] proj = {"*"};
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        Cursor c = cr.query(uri, proj, null, null, null);

        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                /*String[] col = c.getColumnNames();
                String str = "";
                for(int i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                    str = str + col[i] + ": " + c.getString(i) + ", ";
                }
                System.out.println(str);*/
                //System.out.println("--------------------MMS------------------");
                Msg msg = new Msg(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                msg.setThread(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("thread_id")));
                msg.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")));
                msg.setAddr(getMmsAddr(msg.getID()));


                ParseMMS(msg);
                //System.out.println(msg);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        c.close();

    }

}
```

As one can see, a lot of the important MMS data is in this table, such as the date of the message, the message id and the thread id.  You need to use that message ID to pull more information from MMS.

The MMS message is divided into smaller parts of data.  Each part contains something different, like an image, or a text portion.  You have to iterate each part as I do below.

```
public void ParseMMS(Msg msg) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms/part");
        String mmsId = "mid = " + msg.getID();
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, mmsId, null, null);
        while(c.moveToNext()) {
/*          String[] col = c.getColumnNames();
            String str = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                str = str + col[i] + ": " + c.getString(i) + ", ";
            }
            System.out.println(str);*/

            String pid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            String type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ct"));
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                msg.setBody(msg.getBody() + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("text")));
            } else if (type.contains("image")) {
                msg.setImg(getMmsImg(pid));
            }


        }
        c.close();
        return;
    }
```

Each part as the mid field which corresponds to the id of the message found earlier.  We search the MMS part library only for that mms id and then iterate the different parts found.  `ct` or `content_type` as described in the documentation described what the part is, i.e. text, image, etc. I scan the type to see what to do with that part.  If it's plain text, I add that text to the current message body (apparently there can be multiple text parts, but I haven't seen it, but I believe it) and if it's an image, than load the image into a bitmap.  I imagine Bitmaps will be easy to send with java to my computer, but who knows, maybe want to just load it as a byte array.

Anyway, here is how one will get the image data from the MMS part.

```
public Bitmap getMmsImg(String id) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms/part/" + id);
    InputStream in = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try {
        in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        if(in != null)
            in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

You know, I'm not entirely sure how opening an input stream on the content resolver really works and how it is giving me just the image and not like all the other data, no clue, but it seems to work.  I stole this one from some different sources while looking for solutions.

The MMS addresses aren't as straight forward to pull as they are for SMS, but here is how you can get them all.  The only thing I haven't been able to do is figure out who the sender was.  I'd love it if someone knew that.

```
public String getMmsAddr(String id) {
        String sel = new String("msg_id=" + id);
        String uriString = MessageFormat.format("content://mms/{0}/addr", id);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, sel, null, null);
        String name = "";
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
/*          String[] col = c.getColumnNames();
            String str = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                str = str + col[i] + ": " + c.getString(i) + ", ";
            }
            System.out.println(str);*/
            String t = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
            if(!(t.contains("insert")))
                name = name + t + " ";
        }
        c.close();
        return name;
}
```

This was all just for MMS.  The good news is that SMS is much simpler.

```
public void ScanSMS() {
        System.out.println("==============================ScanSMS()==============================");
        //Initialize Box
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
        String[] proj = {"*"};
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        Cursor c = cr.query(uri,proj,null,null,null);

        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String[] col = c.getColumnNames();
                String str = "";
                for(int i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                    str = str + col[i] + ": " + c.getString(i) + ", ";
                }
                //System.out.println(str);

                System.out.println("--------------------SMS------------------");

                Msg msg = new Msg(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                msg.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")));
                msg.setAddr(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Address")));
                msg.setBody(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body")));
                msg.setDirection(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("type")));
                msg.setContact(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("person")));
                System.out.println(msg);


            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
}
```

Here is my simple message structure so anyone may compile the above code quickly if wanted.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

/**
 * Created by rbenedict on 3/16/2016.
 */

//import java.util.Date;

public class Msg {
    private String id;
    private String t_id;
    private String date;
    private String dispDate;
    private String addr;
    private String contact;
    private String direction;
    private String body;
    private Bitmap img;
    private boolean bData;
    //Date vdat;

    public Msg(String ID) {
        id = ID;
        body = "";
    }

    public void setDate(String d) {
        date = d;
        dispDate = msToDate(date);
    }
    public void setThread(String d) { t_id = d; }

    public void setAddr(String a) {
        addr = a;
    }
    public void setContact(String c) {
        if (c==null) {
            contact = "Unknown";
        } else {
            contact = c;
        }
    }
    public void setDirection(String d) {
        if ("1".equals(d))
            direction = "FROM: ";
        else
            direction = "TO: ";

    }
    public void setBody(String b) {
        body = b;
    }
    public void setImg(Bitmap bm) {
        img = bm;
        if (bm != null)
            bData = true;
        else
            bData = false;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public String getDispDate() {
        return dispDate;
    }
    public String getThread() { return t_id; }
    public String getID() { return id; }
    public String getBody() { return body; }
    public Bitmap getImg() { return img; }
    public boolean hasData() { return bData; }

    public String toString() {

        String s = id + ". " + dispDate + " - " + direction + " " + contact + " " + addr + ": "  + body;
        if (bData)
            s = s + "\nData: " + img;
        return s;
    }

    public String msToDate(String mss) {

        long time = Long.parseLong(mss,10);

        long sec = ( time / 1000 ) % 60;
        time = time / 60000;

        long min = time % 60;
        time = time / 60;

        long hour = time % 24 - 5;
        time = time / 24;

        long day = time % 365;
        time = time / 365;

        long yr = time + 1970;

        day = day - ( time / 4 );
        long mo = getMonth(day);
        day = getDay(day);

        mss = String.valueOf(yr) + "/" + String.valueOf(mo) + "/" + String.valueOf(day) + " " + String.valueOf(hour) + ":" + String.valueOf(min) + ":" + String.valueOf(sec);

        return mss;
    }
    public long getMonth(long day) {
        long[] calendar = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if(day < calendar[i]) {
                return i + 1;
            } else {
                day = day - calendar[i];
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
    public long getDay(long day) {
        long[] calendar = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if(day < calendar[i]) {
                return day;
            } else {
                day = day - calendar[i];
            }
        }
        return day;
    }



}
```

Some final comments and notes on this solution.

The person field seems to always be NULL and later I plan to implement a contact look up.  I also haven't been able to identify who sent the MMS message.

I am not super familiar with java and I am still learning it.  I am positive there is a data container (ArrayList) (Vector?) that could hold a user defined object.  And if sortable by a specific field in the object (date), one could iterate that list and have a chronological order of all the message: both MMS/SMS and both sent/received.

Comment: Great answer @Chemistpp. Do you know how do we get SIM detail for multi sim mobiles above android 5.1? I don't see any column that stores sim detail.

Comment: @Riz Hah, well I thought if I was gonna be a dbag and answer my own question, I ought to do it well.  I couldn't accept it.  It was too much hahaha.  Anyway, I don't know about the sim id.  Several things suggest it is not possible from the sms.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311299/how-to-use-reflection-in-android-for-sending-sms-from-second-sim-slot and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051023/how-to-get-current-sim-card-number-in-android