# Trying to read SMS/MMS on Android and geting java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver, android-mms, android-sms

I'm trying to read SMS/MMS on Android, and I have followed the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6446831/2415237), when writing the code and try to run it on an Android OS 6.0.1 on Samsung device I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1626)
                      at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                      at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                      at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
                      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:502)
                      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:445)
                      at com.my.code.services.ListenSmsMmsService$SMSObserver.onChange(ListenSmsMmsService.java:102)
```

This is the code that is creating the exception:

```
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);


            /*first of all we need to decide message is Text or MMS type.*/
            final String[] projection = new String[] {"*"};

            Uri mainUri = Telephony.MmsSms.CONTENT_CONVERSATIONS_URI; //URI for query


            Cursor mainCursor = contentResolver.query(mainUri, projection, null, null, null);
```

The last line is the one that causes the crash.
even if I used:

```
Uri mainUri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
```

and:

```
final String[] projection = new String[]{"_id", "ct_t"};
```

or:

```
final String[] projection = new String[]{Telephony.MmsSms.TYPE_DISCRIMINATOR_COLUMN};
```

the crash happen.

When I tried to run a query on `ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI` the query was successfull.

What can be the problem, that causes the crash?

Comment: *contentResolver.query(mainUri, project, null, null, null);* **project** or **projection** ?

Comment: if you change with this uri: content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true

Comment: `CONTENT_CONVERSATIONS_URI` is meant to be used with a `thread_id` to return all of the messages in a single conversation. Apparently on some devices, you can query without one, and just get the list that `content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true` would return, which should be the list of separate conversations, but I know (at least some) Samsungs won't have it. What are you trying to get, exactly? A single conversation? The list of conversations? Every message ever, no matter the conversation it belongs to?

Comment: Thank you @toto, using your uri prevented the crash. But the projection didn't work.

Comment: @Mike-M what I try to do is to get notified on any TextMessage (either SMS or MMS) that is received by the device. I also want to differentiate between SMS and MMS, and I have used the code sample in the answer I have quoted and it is not working, is there a way to do this differentiate? Is this: 'content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true' URI is only working on Samsung devices and if the code will run on other device it will not work?

Comment: TRY IT: String[] projection = {"Conversations._ID", "Conversations.ADDRESS", "Conversations.BODY"};

Comment: This projection will not allow me to know if this message is SMS or MMS. How I can achieve this?

Comment: "what I try to do is to get notified on any TextMessage..." - Querying the Provider is not going to give you a real-time notification of messages. It just returns the messages already saved when you do the query. "Is this ... URI is only working on Samsung..." - That URI should work everywhere that uses the standard API; i.e., any device where the OEM hasn't altered it. However, as mentioned, that's just going to return a list of conversation summaries, not the individual messages in them. If you want a list of every message, have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36439630).

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example of getting real time notification of mesages? BTW in my question I wrote that using what you wrote in the answer you pointed me to: 'final String[] projection = new String[]{Telephony.MmsSms.TYPE_DISCRIMINATOR_COLUMN};' also makes the code crash.

Comment: There are lots of examples on-site for receiving SMS. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11435354) has the basics, though the message handling is slightly wrong, and a little outdated for API 19+. MMS is similar, but it's probable that your app won't get MMS with a Receiver on API 19+ if it's not the default messaging app, in which case a `ContentObserver` can be used. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14452808) goes pretty in-depth on Receivers for both. As for my answer I linked above, look closely. It uses a different `Uri` than what you have; it's not `CONTENT_CONVERSATIONS_URI`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens on many other Samsung devices: 
seems that on these devices, you can't query for `content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true` without the `?simple=true` suffix - and when you add this suffix, it affects the returned columns, and that's why the projection failed.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13640868/997940) for more related info about this, though no one really knows why it behaves this way :(

There might be a workaround, using an undocumented URI of `content://mms-sms/complete-conversations` - as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36439630/997940).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Samsung devices, so for just SMS conversations, I tried doing grouping by thread id on the SMS table [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62419933/8879841).

Unfortunately `content://mms-sms/complete-conversations` doesn't seem to aggregate on the thread id like `content://mms-sms/conversations` does, so you end up with multiple messages from the same thread.